# "Unspecified Exception" when running .command bash script

Tags: bash, macos, exception, unspecified

I've created a bash script to play some music using the `afplay` command.  I used the file extension `.command` so that it can be opened with a double click in finder. This is an abbreviation of the code.

```
#! /bin/bash

afplay playlist/01.m4a
```

The script works when I manually run it through terminal, but when I open the .command file through finder all I get is,

```
admins-iMac:~ user$ /Users/admin/Documents/bash/music.command ; exit;
Unspecified exception
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

And no music is played. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's displayed if you modify your script to first do `echo $PWD` and `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: `admins-iMac:~ user$ /Users/admin/Documents/bash/music.command ; exit;
Unspecified exception
/Users/admin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]`

Comment: What is the full path of your playlist directory - is it actually in `/Users/admin`, or some lower level subdirectory ?  If the latter, I'm wondering if try putting the full path in the script, something like "afplay /Users/admin/Documents/whatever/playlist/01.m4a`

Comment: The error is thrown by `afplay` executable. I think why `afplay` is throwing the error is out of scope for [so]. You'd get better results on [su]. If `afplay` has options like `--verbose`/`--debug` you might want to pass those options to it for better understanding of the issue. Also, try running the `afplay playlist/01.m4a` command directly from the terminal, instead of adding `;exit` after it. No point in exiting the terminal, if the command is failing anyway.

Comment: Ah, it worked when I put the full file path. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm getting apparently random Unspecified Result errors using combinations of 'afplay', '/usr/bin/afplay' as the program name and 'file.WAV' '/Volumes/ExternalHD/dir1/dir2/file.WAV' as the sound file, conducting tests over a period of 5-10 minutes. To add to the fun, when I call afplay from a shell script it fails more often than the identical call from the command line. My conclusion is that there is another process or system state that is interfering with afplay.

Answer (score 0):

No clue why but:
`afplay my`
played fine while
`mv my{,.mp3} && afplay my.mp3` won't and will exit with "Unspecified exception"